# slick slider arrow click tracking

Tags: google-analytics, slick.js

I'm wracking my head here. Slider works, that's not the issue. I've been ask to add event tracking to the arrow. So not on a slide change as the KPI is which arrow. So did the user click left or right.

This does't work:

```js
    $('.slick-arrow').on('click', function () {
      var $this = $(this),
        $ariaLabel = $this.attr('aria-label');


      console.log('button');
    });
```

The arrows are default, though I changed the css. Is there another way to track arrow clicks?

Comment: can you comment on how GA is implemented? Copy and paste the GA snippet that's on the page.

Comment: It's done through tag manager, but implementation isn't the issue. It's a call back on the click I'm trying to solve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this will help you track your button.

In GTM, create a user-defined variable of "auto-event variable" type and value would be the "aria-label" attribute like so:
[image]

Then create a trigger for the arrow clicks, you already have the right idea for targetting the element using the CSS classes, but this can be done in GTM, like so:
[image]
Note, if you don't see the "Click XXXX" variables, you can enable them under the "built-in variables" section in the variables screen.

Next create the event tag, you'll go to the tags page and create a new tag of type Google Analytics, then pick "event" for track type and fill in the category, action and label as you wish. Note, here I'm using the variable we created in the first step as the label, but you can put it anywhere to identify what kind of arrow it was. Make sure to also pick the trigger we created earlier as the trigger for this tag as well.
[image]

After this is all done, put the container in debug mode and you should see the tag fire and register an event in GA.